# Replace IMG tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm not that good with this REGEX string replace, but i think this problem can be solved with that...

I want to replace this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">
<img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-112" height="300" src="http://www.example.comsample1.png" title="sample1" width="300" /></a>
```

with this:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.example.com">
<img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-112" height="300" src="http://www.example.comsample1.png" title="sample1" width="300" /></a></p>
```

and this (if no link given):

```
<img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-112" height="300" src="http://www.example.comsample1.png" title="sample1" width="300" />
```

with this:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
<img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-112" height="300" src="http://www.example.comsample1.png" title="sample1" width="300" /></p>
```

How can i make this work? (the search keyword is the  'class="aligncenter ', if this exist in the IMG tag, then i need to replace)

There could be many IMG or  tags to replace, not only one!

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: If you're not good with a certain technology, you shouldn't pick it without first considering simpler options. See some of the related links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably need two regexps, one for img (making sure that there's no `<a` before or after `<img />` tag, that what's [look ahead](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), you'll need **negative look ahead assertion** so it will look like this:

```
$text = preg_replace( '~<img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-112"([^<>]+)/>\s*(?!</a)~mi', '<p style="text-align:center;">\0</p>', $text);
```

`m` will match new lines in `\s*` and `i` makes regexp case insensitive, `\0` reffers to whole matched text

Replace for `<a ...><img />` will be similar:

```
$text = preg_replace( '~<a href="([^"]+)"><img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-112"([^<>]+)/>\s*</a>~mi', '<p style="text-align:center;">\0</p>', $text);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :) If i just want the 'class="aligncenter' fot the match, what do i need to change? (the rest can be differenct)

Comment: @VORiAND try to play with it for a while so you'll get used to it :) but basically all you need is replace `"aligncenter size-full wp-image-112"` with `"[^"]*aligncenter[^"]*"`. (and mark this answer as answer when you don't need any more extensive help)